# gammu sendsms return error 29

Tags: php, ubuntu, sms-gateway, gammu

i am currently working on a SMS gateway project.
running on ubuntu 13.04 and using gammu.
installed and configured gammu and then i used

```
gammu --identify
```

and the result was

```
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB0
Manufacturer         : Wavecom
Model                : MULTIBAND  900E  1800 (MULTIBAND  900E  1800)
Firmware             : 65209gg.Q2406B 244 112706 01:12
IMEI                 : 353805012839937
SIM IMSI             : 510101262086274
```

then i tried

```
gammu getallsms
```

and it worked, but the problem is when i tried to send sms using

```
gammu sendsms TEXT [number] -text "SMS Test"
```

it returned

```
    If you want break, press Ctrl+C...
    Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..error 29, message   reference=-1
Unknown error.
```

here is my gammurc file

```
  port = /dev/ttyUSB0
model = 
connection = at115200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /var/log/gammulog
logformat = textall
use_locking = 
gammuloc =
```

and this is my gammu-smsd file

```
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at115200
```

and here is my gammu log

```
[Gammu            - 1.33.0 built 16:20:47 Aug  1 2013 using GCC 4.8]
[Connection       - "at115200"]
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.11.0-12-generic (#19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013)]
Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is down, CTS is up
Setting speed to 115200
[Module           - "auto"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "HEX""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "HEX"....OK.. 
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 " WAVECOM MODEM"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x20/32
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |20 |57W|41A|56V|45E|43C AT+CGMI... WAVEC
4FO|4DM|20 |4DM|4FO|44D|45E|4DM|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  OM MODEM....OK..
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: Wavecom]
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("GSM","PCCP437","CUSTOM","HEX")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x3B/59
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|50P|43C|43C|50P|344 S: ("GSM","PCCP4
333|377|22"|2C,|22"|43C|55U|53S|54T|4FO|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|48H|45E 37","CUSTOM","HE
58X|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      X")....OK..     
Chosen HEX as normal charset
Getting model
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D                                  AT+CGMM.        
1 "AT+CGMM"
2 " MULTIBAND  900E  1800 "
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x29/41
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D |0D |0A |20 |4DM|55U|4CL|54T|49I AT+CGMM... MULTI
42B|41A|4EN|44D|20 |20 |399|300|300|45E|20 |20 |311|388|300|300 BAND  900E  1800
20 |0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                               ....OK..       
[Model name: `MULTIBAND  900E  1800']
[Model data: `MULTIBAND  900E  1800']
[Model data: `MULTIBAND  900E  1800']
[Connected model  - "MULTIBAND  900E  1800"]
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
[Module           - "A2D|iPAQ|at|M20|S25|MC35|TC35|C35i|S65|S300|5110|5130|5190|5210|6110|6130|6150|6190|6210|6250|6310|6310i|6510|7110|8210|8250|8290|8310|8390|8850|8855|8890|8910|9110|9210"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "HEX""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "HEX"....OK.. 
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 " WAVECOM MODEM"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x20/32
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |20 |57W|41A|56V|45E|43C AT+CGMI... WAVEC
4FO|4DM|20 |4DM|4FO|44D|45E|4DM|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  OM MODEM....OK..
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: Wavecom]
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("GSM","PCCP437","CUSTOM","HEX")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x3B/59
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|50P|43C|43C|50P|344 S: ("GSM","PCCP4
333|377|22"|2C,|22"|43C|55U|53S|54T|4FO|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|48H|45E 37","CUSTOM","HE
58X|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      X")....OK..     
Chosen HEX as normal charset
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
Setting date & time
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|311|366|2F/|300|366|2F/|322 AT+CCLK="16/06/2
399|2C,|311|300|3A:|300|300|3A:|344|366|2B+|300|300|22"|0D      9,10:00:46+00". 
1 "AT+CCLK="16/06/29,10:00:46+00""
2 "+CME ERROR: 3"
Checking line: +CME ERROR: 3
AT reply state: 6
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x30/48
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|311|366|2F/|300|366|2F/|322 AT+CCLK="16/06/2
399|2C,|311|300|3A:|300|300|3A:|344|366|2B+|300|300|22"|0D |0D  9,10:00:46+00"..
0A |2B+|43C|4DM|45E|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |333|0D |0A  .+CME ERROR: 3..
CME Error 3: "operation not allowed"
Getting firmware versions
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D                                  AT+CGMR.        
1 "AT+CGMR"
2 "65209gg.Q2406B 244 112706 01:12"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x31/49
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D |0D |0A |366|355|322|300|399|67g AT+CGMR...65209g
67g|2E.|51Q|322|344|300|366|42B|20 |322|344|344|20 |311|311|322 g.Q2406B 244 112
377|300|366|20 |300|311|3A:|311|322|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D  706 01:12....OK.
0A                                                              .               
Received firmware version: "65209gg.Q2406B 244 112706 01:12"
Number version is "65209.240624"
[Firmware version - "65209gg.Q2406B 244 112706 01:12"]
[Connected]
Entering GSM_SetIncomingUSSD
Enabling incoming USSD
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CUSD=1.      
1 "AT+CUSD=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CUSD=1...OK..
Leaving GSM_SetIncomingUSSD
Entering GSM_DialService
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0E/14
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D          AT+CSCS="GSM".  
1 "AT+CSCS="GSM""
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0D |0A  AT+CSCS="GSM"...
4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x2C/44
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|311|2C,|22"|2A*|377|377|377|2A* AT+CUSD=1,"*777*
300|388|311|322|333|322|355|355|322|322|344|344|2A*|322|355|2A* 081232552244*25*
355|355|322|311|344|388|23#|22"|2C,|311|355|0D                  552148#",15.    
1 "AT+CUSD=1,"*777*081232552244*25*552148#",15"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x32/50
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|311|2C,|22"|2A*|377|377|377|2A* AT+CUSD=1,"*777*
300|388|311|322|333|322|355|355|322|322|344|344|2A*|322|355|2A* 081232552244*25*
355|355|322|311|344|388|23#|22"|2C,|311|355|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK 552148#",15...OK
0D |0A                                                          ..              
Incoming USSD received
Leaving GSM_DialService
1 "+CUSD: 2,"Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348.",15"
Checking line: +CUSD: 2,"Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348.",15
AT reply state: 4
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x8F/143
2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3A:|20 |322|2C,|22"|50P|65e|6Dm|62b|65e|6Cl +CUSD: 2,"Pembel
69i|61a|6En|20 |311|20 |62b|75u|61a|68h|20 |76v|6Fo|75u|63c|68h ian 1 buah vouch
65e|72r|20 |3C<|53S|69i|6Dm|50P|41A|54T|49I|3E>|20 |73s|65e|6En er <SimPATI> sen
69i|6Cl|61a|69i|20 |3C<|322|355|3E>|20 |75u|6En|74t|75u|6Bk|20  ilai <25> untuk 
3C<|300|388|311|322|333|322|355|355|322|322|344|344|20 |74t|65e <081232552244 te
6Cl|61a|68h|20 |62b|65e|72r|68h|61a|73s|69i|6Cl|2E.|20 |53S|4EN lah berhasil. SN
20 |3C<|366|300|366|322|399|311|300|300|300|333|300|322|311|311  <60629100030211
333|333|311|322|300|3E>|2E.|53S|74t|6Fo|6Bk|20 |61a|6En|64d|61a 33120>.Stok anda
20 |322|355|4BK|3D=|333|344|388|2E.|22"|2C,|311|355|0D |0A       25K=348.",15.. 
Incoming USSD received
Parsing +CUSD: 2,"Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348.",15
 with +CUSD: @i @0
Parsed int 2
Status: 2
Parsing +CUSD: 2,"Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348.",15
 with +CUSD: @i, @s @0
Parsed int 2
Grabbed string from reply: "Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348." (parsed 129 bytes)
Parsed generic string "Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348."
Generic string decoded as "Pembelian 1 buah voucher <SimPATI> senilai <25> untuk <081232552244 telah berhasil. SN <6062910003021133120>.Stok anda 25K=348."
1 "+CMTI: "SM",3"
Checking line: +CMTI: "SM",3
AT reply state: 4
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0F/15
2B+|43C|4DM|54T|49I|3A:|20 |22"|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|333|0D |0A      +CMTI: "SM",3.. 
Incoming SMS
Entering GSM_SetIncomingUSSD
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0E/14
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D          AT+CSCS="HEX".  
1 "AT+CSCS="HEX""
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D |0D |0A  AT+CSCS="HEX"...
4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "HEX""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "HEX"....OK.. 
Terminating possible incoming USSD
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|322|0D                          AT+CUSD=2.      
1 "AT+CUSD=2"
2 "+CME ERROR: 3"
Checking line: +CME ERROR: 3
AT reply state: 6
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1B/27
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|45E AT+CUSD=2...+CME
20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |333|0D |0A                       ERROR: 3..     
CME Error 3: "operation not allowed"
Disabling incoming USSD
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|300|0D                          AT+CUSD=0.      
1 "AT+CUSD=0"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|55U|53S|44D|3D=|300|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CUSD=0...OK..
Leaving GSM_SetIncomingUSSD
[Terminating]
[Closing]
```

***UPDATE***

this problem only happened when i stopped gammu-smsd service.
but when i started gammu-smsd service the problem was

> No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected.

does anyone have idea what's wrong about that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post log from sending SMS? It's overwritten on each invocation and your one is from dialservice command not showing the error...

Answer (score 1):

You can not use both gammu and gammu-smsd at same time on one device, so breakages are expected in such case.